# Redirecting New Facebook Login Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, omniauth, facebook-login, omniauth-facebook

When a new user signs up to my website they are redirected to a personal tutorial. This is currently working for users who sign up on the site. However, when a new user clicks "sign in with facebook" they are redirected to the wrong URL (The url they would get if they have signed in before that bypasses the tutorial). Can anyone help me set it up so new Facebook users are redirected to the tutorial and existing Facebook bypass it? (I have the omniauth-facebook gem installed)

Here is my code. Thanks for taking the time to look this over!

User.controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_signin, except: [:new, :create]
  before_action :require_correct_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :image, :tutorial]
  before_action :require_admin, only: [:index, :destroy]


def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params) 
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to users_tutorial_url (@user)
  else
    render :new
  end 
end

def tutorial
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :born_in, :gender, :password, :password_confirmation)
end


def require_correct_user
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
   redirect_to products_url unless current_user? (@user)
 end
end
```

Session.controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to(session[:intended_url] || filtered_products_path(:trending))
      session[:intended_url] = nil
    elsif 
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to(session[:intended_url] || filtered_products_path(:trending))
    session[:intended_url] = nil
    else  
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid email/password combination!"
      render :new
  end
end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

User.rb (User Model)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }


def self.authenticate(email, password)
  user = User.find_by(email: email)
  user && user.authenticate(password)
end


def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.email = auth.info.email
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save(:validate => false)  
    end
  end

end
```

omniauth.rb
    OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'Facebook Key ###', 'Facebook Secret ###'  
end
```